# Get taxonomy and check if published?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am trying to display taxonomy programitcally.
The problem is, all taxonomy is displayed whther published all not. How can I filter only published taxonomy.

I use this code to get taxonomy.

```
$tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree(
  'vocabulary_name',
  0,
  1, 
  TRUE               
);
 
$results = [];
 
foreach ($tree as $term) {
  $results[] = $term->getName();
}
```

Can I add a filter like status->1, or status = pubished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TermStorage::loadTree()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/10) is just a fancy way to load term entities. The first mode is a "quick mode" that skims data from `taxonomy_term_data`. The second mode is just a regular `loadMultiple()` that loads full entities using the IDs from the quick mode. Since you're interested in status data, you will be loading full entities instead of the quick mode.

Since you already have hold of the term storage service, you can just use [`loadByProperties()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3AloadByProperties/10). Filter against the `vid`, `status`, and `parent` properties.

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
    ->loadByProperties([
      'vid' => 'vocabulary_name',
      'parent' => 0,
      'status' => 1,
    ])
```